# Facebook 3.0 SDK Beta - should i use it in a final deploy?

Tags: ios, facebook

i need to integrate Facebook to share some links within my app. I´ve never used the "old" SDK before. Just created a dummy project to test it.

After reading the announcement about the 3.0 SDK beta, i´m interested about using this beta version within a final app-store app. What do you think about? Does that make sense? I just would need it for sharing links.. I would love to use 3.0 because of the easier integration, so therefore my question...

Thanks for your opinion..

Comment: I would recommend against using BETA software for release apps.

Comment: It's far more stable than their previous crappy "non-beta" 2.0.

Comment: @Mugunth Not even a week has passed since it has been released **in beta** - how do you know that it is _far more stable_? Not even Facebook knows how stable it actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually depends on how much risk you are willing to take.

My opinion is that the integration of the old sdk is not that difficult. More over it is safe. Besides there are official tutorials showing you step by step what to do:

[iOS Tutorial #socialchannels](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#socialchannels)
[Mobile Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

The sdk 3.0 is a gigantic step forward. Anyway I'd just wait until it is out of beta and then push an update.

Answer (score -3):

I'm using it in an app. I haven't encountered any show stopping bug as of now.